# Left & right adjoints in the context of posets.

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

**Definition 1:** A function $\theta: X\to Y$ between posets is *monotone* if whenever $x\le y$, we have $\theta (x)\le\theta (y)$.

**Definition 2:** For any pair $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ of monotone maps, we say $g$ is a *left adjoint* of $f$ and $f$ is a *right adjoint* of $g$ if $$g(b)\le a\Leftrightarrow b\le f(a).$$

> **Theorem:** Left adjoints preserve all joins; right adjoints preserve all meets.

I'm not at all sure how to prove this theorem (and it's actually a lemma in a paper). It looks like (it should be easy and) we can cut it in half since the argument for left adjoints looks set to be dual to that of right adjoints. I've taken an arbitrary join then hit it with $g$ (for such a pair $f, g$ as in Definition 2). Now what?

Please help :)

Comment: Which paper is this lemma in?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm at liberty to say just yet, @SanathDevalapurkar :)

Comment: It's [this one](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.6516.pdf) :)

Comment: Interesting, though I must say that I probably won't be able to understand it, since I'm not an expert at order theory.

Comment: Nor am I $\ddot\smile$

Comment: How is this *not* category theory? A monotone function is just a functor between the posets, what you described is precisely an adjunction between functors, and it's probably possible to interpret meets and joins as (co)limits. So why the disclaimer?

Comment: Fair enough, @NajibIdrissi :)

Comment: I just didn't recognize it, that's all; I'm self-taught in category theory :)

Comment: Well, I recognized it enough to think it would lead me astray . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It boils down to category theory, and the fact that if $L:\mathcal{C}\leftrightarrows\mathcal{D}: R$ is a pair of adjoint functors, then one of them (I can never remember which, but it's easy to figure out) preserves all limits, while the other preserves all colimits.

A poset $(P,\prec)$ can be viewed as a category $\mathcal{P}$ with object set $P$ and for all $x,y\in P$,
$$\mathcal{P}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\lbrace *\rbrace & \text{if }x\leq y\\\emptyset &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
(Composition need not be defined as there is only one way to do it). This way, monotone maps between two posets are exactly the functors between the associated categories, and Galois correspondences (pairs of monotone maps that satisfy the condition from your second difinition) are exactly pairs of adjoint functors.

Here you'll take $\mathcal{C}=A$ and $\mathcal{D}=B$. To finish, you only need to understand that the meet of a subset $A\subset P$ is the categorical limit of the (inclusion) functor $\iota:\mathcal{A}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{P}$, while the join is its the colimit.

Comment: So it *was* category theory! I should have known! Thank you :)

Comment: @Shaun My pleasure :) ${}$

Comment: "I can never remember which" Left adjoints = maps are going out. Colimits = maps are going out. Hence, left adjoints preserve colimits.

Comment: I have a [follow-up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827119/left-right-adjoints-in-the-context-of-complete-lattices) :)

Comment: @OlivierBégassat "I can never remember which": Awodey teaches "Right adjoints preserve limits = RAPL". So just remember RAPL and use duality for left adjoints

Comment: @magma I'll try, unfortunately there are no Raplosoaurs. Maybe Grappling hooks?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question had been answered, but I'd like to point out that there is a fairly easy proof that does not involve category theory. We only need the following characterisation of joints:

**Lemma:** *Let $(X, \leq)$ be a poset, $Y \subseteq X$ a subset. Then an element $z \in X$ is the joint of $Y$ if and only if for any $x \in X$ we have*
$$
(\forall y \in Y : y \leq x) \Leftrightarrow z \leq x
$$
This lemma is easily proved by using the definition of joint as smallest upper bound.

Back to the question at hand (using your definition of $A$, $B$, $f$ and $g$): Let $Z \subseteq A$ be a set such that $z = \sup Z$ exists in $A$. To show that $f$ preserves joints, we must have $\sup f(Z) = f(z)$, or equivalently, we must have for all $b \in B$
$$
(\forall y \in Y: f(y) \leq b) \Leftrightarrow f(z) \leq b
$$
by the lemma above. And this we have, as the following calculation shows:
$$
\forall y \in Y : f(y) \leq b \\
\Leftrightarrow \forall y \in Y : y \leq g(b) \\
\Leftrightarrow z \leq g(b) \\
\Leftrightarrow f(z) \leq b
$$
where we again used the lemma for the second equivalence.