# Left & right adjoints in the context of complete lattices.

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, alternative-proof

*This is a follow-up question from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825921/left-right-adjoints-in-the-context-of-posets) of mine.*

In the same paper as the one mentioned in my previous post, it's stated that

> In the context of complete lattices, a monotone map has a right adjoint if
>   and only if it preserves all joins and a monotone map has a left adjoint if
>   and only if it preserves all meets.

I know that $\sup$ & $\inf$ can each be written in terms of join and meet, so I can sort of see why this is true, but how can I see it categorically?

Please help :)

Comment: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/the-adjoint-functor-theorem-for-posets/

Comment: Thank you, @QiaochuYuan :)

Comment: A shorter way of summarizing the argument is that a left resp. right adjoint is characterized as representing a certain functor, and provided that you know that that functor preserves colimits resp. limits you can, in a poset with all colimits resp. limits, just build the representing object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an immediate consequence of Freyd's general adjoint functor theorem. The solution set condition is empty for small categories, in particular for small preorders. This is explained very well in the [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem).

Comment: Ah, I see! I've **just** remembered that, last year, I wrote myself a quite a lot of notes on adjoints for preorders and Freyd's adjoint functor theorem, based on Maclane's masterpiece. It shouldn't be too difficult for me to understand it quite thoroughly now. Thank you! I'm sorry about my annoying, uninformed enthusiasm with Category Theory by the way. It just shows up everywhere and it's so beautiful! :)